# /s getting added to community URL

Tags: community, url

We have two sand boxes. In one sandbox, /s is getting added to community url where as in another sandbox it is not. Custom Login page is specified as active site home page in both boxes.So Login page is shown when I copy & paste the community URL where there is no /s. If I copy and paste the community URL from sandbox where there is /s it gives following error message. How can I fix this issue?

```
 URL No Longer Exists
 You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer exists on salesforce.com. 

 You may have reached this page after clicking on a direct link into the 
 application. This direct link might be: 
 • A bookmark to a particular page, such as a report or view 
 • A link to a particular page in the Custom Links section of your Home Tab, 
   or a Custom Link 
 • A link to a particular page in your email templates 

 If you reached this page through a bookmark, you are probably trying to 
 access something that has moved. Please update your bookmark. 

 If you reached this page through any of the other direct links listed 
 above, please notify your administrator to update the link. 

 Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using 
 salesforce.com!
```

Answer (score 1):

The /s/ in a community URL (or at the end) means that the page was built using the community builder. Most of the new templates are built on top of the community builder.

URLs without the /s/ mean that they are force.com URLs (usually built using visualforce).

So check you are using same template in both sandbox. You need to change your template.

Comment: Tushar,Our login page is custom visual force page, it is not built using community builder. I checked the site template in both sandbox. It is blank that is found(seen) when I click on customer community link under site label column. But template is customer service(napili) in both sandboxes which is is seen on Administration -> Settings on community.